# Build frame for page content using CSS

Tags: html, css

[image]

Hi guys, I need to do such frame with css. And I have 8 images (4 top and bottom corners and 4 images that will be repeated).
This frame should be resizeable, so I can adjust it to the screen dimensions using javascript.

The problem is I have no idea how to do it. I tried to google for tutorial but fail at that.

Could someone point me a direction to dig in to?
So I have a place to start. Some tutorial or example how people do it)
Will be very appreciate, thank you)

P.S.

I know how to resize images. 
I dont know how to combine `div's` to have header like green one.
Having two corners and resizeable element in the middle.

Comment: SO is not a drive-through code generator. Please try to have a go at this yourself. There are plenty of tutorials around.

Comment: No effort, no progress.

Comment: Did you try searching for anything?  "CSS Gradients" or "CSS Rounded Corners" maybe?

Comment: any link to tutorial? I do not need ready code, just link for any tutorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Except for header background, you won't need any other images. You can use a div for header with image background and 100% width, another div as the outer "square" with background and border and padding/margin, then  div with white background and border radius (http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_border-radius.asp). (You could also do gradient from header background by using css3 but it's not well adopted by browsers yet).

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do this with css3 ... you should use `border-radius` and `box-shadow` css properties

read this: http://www.css3.info/preview/rounded-border/ and http://www.css3.info/preview/box-shadow/

Comment: you could ask this over chat room ... it's faster and more appropriate. ;)

Answer (score 1):

I made a simple [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uTHwk/) and i hope it will help. I only used `border-radius` from css3 selectors.You could use gradient to achieve the gradient effect in header.